# what is core purpose of IDE refractor option?

Tags: php, eclipse, netbeans, ide

To change name of folder or file NET-BEANS and ECLIPSE IDE both offer an option i.e. REFRACTOR

What actually is the core purpose of this option? or other way around how can we get benefit from this option while development

PLEASE explain it with some hello word type example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactoring is a major feature in agile software development. It came about as the third step in test-driven development:

1. Write a test
2. Write enough code to pass the test
3. Refactor

To refactor means the code is working, but it needs to be cleaned up to be more maintainable and extensible. This could be something simple like renaming a variable or extracting common code into a function or something complicated like extracting an interface or adding a design pattern.

I don't have numbers, but I think the majority of developers don't do TDD. Still, you should refactor often to clean up technical debt (another agile term) and make your code maintainable and extensible. It is such a huge help when you need to add a bunch of new features in a short amount of time.

So all these IDE's, regardless of language or platform, offer automated refactorings to make your life easier. For example, changing a method name in a Java class and then changing it everywhere it is referenced would be a huge pain to do manually.

Hope that helps.

Comment: you mean to say that if i rename a  project file in IDE it will rename it at every single place where it is referenced from or link from.

Comment: Yes the IDE will rename all references for renamed variables, methods and classes. Eclipse can even search text files (such as XML plug-in configuration) for references to renamed classes,

Answer (score 0):

According to [here:](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?WhatIsRefactoring)

> "Refactoring is the process of changing a software system in such a
>   way that it does not alter the external behavior of the code yet
>   improves its internal structure."

The most common usages for this is usually the renaming of variables to something which makes more sense, the fixing of indentations and addition of comments, such as JavaDoc/nDoc.

In certain scenario, one would also require to rewrite some logic, or entire modules of the code. This usually entails either a bad design or else, that the solution had been changed so much that a re-write will ease any future maintenance.